# How many parameters does ios::setstate actually take?

Tags: c++, istream, setstate

Every definition I've seen of function `ios::setstate( iostate state )` shows that the function takes **ONE** and **ONLY ONE** parameter yet when I compile a program with the following function call, everything compiles and runs just fine:

```
mystream.setstate( std::ios_base::badbit, true );
```

What exactly is the second parameter and why is there no documentation about it?

EDIT: I'm using the command line compiler of the latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's required to accept a single argument, as you've noted, but implementations *are* allowed to extend member functions via parameters with default values (§17.6.5.5). In other words, as long as this works:

```
mystream.setstate( std::ios_base::badbit );
```

your compiler is conforming. Nothing says that your code *doesn't* have to work, though.

(Your library implementation has decided that a boolean parameter would be useful to have. You never notice it because it has a default value, but you can still get into implementation-specific territory and provide the argument yourself. Whether or not this is a good idea is obviously another question, but probably not.)

Comment: It could also be an overload.

Comment: And it might be worth noting that [libstdc++ 4.1 doesn't](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/classstd_1_1basic__ios.html#d2212b7e90846e23a7e2b0d651568d42).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, they are equivalent for the most part. I chose to say the statement I did because the allowance for overloads is stated in terms of "expanding" functions with default values.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ha, so that's where you went: to a new moniker! I've been wondering where you were at. You've just been here the whole time. :P

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio C++... how can I find what that second parameter does?  I could not find anything about it in the files "ios" or "ios.cpp"

Comment: @Tech_Guy: You really shouldn't want to know, it's for the implementation to use. The most you can do is poke around the definition and try to trace what it does, but you shouldn't try to use it.

Comment: @GMan: :D You can't get rid of me that easily!

Comment: @Tech_Guy: What GMan said. You're not _supposed_ to know. Use the standard API and move on!

Comment: @Tech_Guy: I poked around for a minute and it seems to be used to raise an exception when the state is set. (Streams can be toggled to use exceptions. I'm guessing how they implement it is as: 1) Do normal io. 2) Stream good? Good. 3) Otherwise, if exceptions are disabled, be done; let the user check the flags. 4) But if exceptions are enabled, clear the bits back to okay (as they should be if exceptions are being used) *and set this bool to true so it throws instead*.)

Comment: Knowing that, by the way, I would argue they took an easy but less clear solution. (It unnecessary fuddles with code that you and I use. We aren't suppose to know anyway, but it still *does*.) They could instead have a `__clear()` method that takes on the behavior of their current `clear()` method. Then just define `clear(x)` to be `__clear(x, false)`, and use `__clear(..., true)` anywhere they used `clear(..., true)`. This keeps the details away from you and I, and raises less questions because it starts with a double-underscore, which is reserved for them by definition.

Comment: @GMan Thank you very much for your help.  I was writing my own getline function and looked at a few of the implementations out there, and the call to this specific function just threw me off a little as I didn't understand what they were trying to do.  And once I compiled my own code and got it work with 2 parameters, I got even more confused.

Comment: @Tech_Guy: No problem. If you found an answer satisfactory, click the check mark next to it. :)